# Hadoop: List of all settings that can be set by client using Configuration class?

Tags: java, configuration, hadoop, documentation

In Hadoop client API there is important class [`Configuration`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration.html) that stores properties for connection to cluster, job to be sent, HDFS. These are just key-value pairs and both key and values are `String`s. There are not list of all meaningful keys that can by used to change map-reduce job settings? That is I need list of all keys that can by used to set properties of `Configuration` that would be later interpreted by client API, namenode or jobtracker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest that you not work with the key/value pairs in the Configuration using the literal key name.  Instead, use the static helper methods on not only the Configuration class itself, but on the other classes that read and write those properties via their helper methods.  These other classes include the input and output format classes,

I recommend this because there is often additional logic in these static helper methods that controls or validates the String conversion to and from non-String property values.

Another way of stating this answer is to look at the javadoc for the static methods on the Configuration class, input format classes, output format classes, etc.  That gives you the complete API you want.  If you persist in wanting to know the valid key names, then look at the source for these same helper methods since that's where the key names are used and defined.

Comment: +1 Thank you for warning it is valuable for me. I did not mention much additional logic in helper methods, I will have closer look now to make sure I'm not missing something important. Still, unless you can provide some additional good reason to not to set `Configuration` properties directly I will avoid using helper methods whenever possible. There are good reasons for this - need for compatibility with different versions of client API (much easier and cleaner to translate keys using dictionary then to replace a lot of code), application architecture reasons, input already comes as strings...

Comment: ..., input already comes as strings, we do our own preformating on those strings, etc.
Until now I have done what you suggest - I have looked on code of helper methods to find keys. I just thought it would be much easier if there was some complete and comprehensive list of them...